# Running node js app inside a container refuse to establish connection with mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am trying to execute node js app inside a a running container while mongo db container is running and up to air  (docker run -d --name mongodb p 27017:27017 mongo)

This is the node js code which work perfectly with ide and throw connection error when running it on container

****FAILED TO CONNECT TO MONGODB
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017****

```
mongoose.connect(
  // `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@mongodb:27017/course-goals?authSource=admin`,
// `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_DB_URL}:27017/course-goals?authSource=admin`,
`mongodb://localhost:27017/course-goals?authSource=admin`,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
     
      console.error(err);
    } else {
   
      app.listen(80);
    }
  }
);
```

I the command for the running the server
`docker run --name server -p 80:80 --rm  server`

node js docker file

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

I need to running it just as described, two separately container exposed port 80 for server and the other  27017 for mongo.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I've used wrong address, instead of using "localhost" we should use "host.docker.internal"
when saying localhost its refer to docker network localhost , but when saying "host.docker.internal" its mean for the hosting machine localhost